# Sending messages with buttons using Discord.net

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have just spent the better part of an hour searching for ways to send a button with a message using Discord.Net. In one of their recent merges with Discord.Net-Labs, they said they added a bunch of things, including buttons. However, checking both of their documentation, I couldn't find any way to add a button to a message. I would appreciate an example and/or link to an example of attaching buttons. Thanks :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is documentation [here](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_basics/message-components/intro.html)

Example from the above link:

```cs
[Command("spawner")]
public async Task Spawn()
{
    var builder = new ComponentBuilder()
        .WithButton("label", "custom-id");

    await ReplyAsync("Here is a button!", components: builder.Build());
}
```

To receive an event when someone interacts with a button, you can subscribe to `DiscordSocketClient.ButtonExecuted`. The handler for this event takes a `SocketMessageComponent` object as an argument.